# Demonstrate existence of $\lim_{x\to 0}$ $f(x) = x \cos \left(\frac{x^2+1}{x}\right)$ with $\varepsilon$-$\delta$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

The goal is to determine the existence of $$\lim_{x\to 0} x \cos\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x}\right)$$ and prove my claim.

Define $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\cos(x^2+1/x)$

So, obviously $\lim_{x\to 0} x = 0$. I am not confident about demonstrating $\lim_{x\to 0} \cos(x^2+1/x)$ exists; however, I saw a result saying that because the latter function is bounded, $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)\cdot g(x) = 0$. I don't think I want to prove this using a limit theorem, rather the epsilon-delta definition.

I'm working on the epsilon-delta form proof hoping some insight will shake out of the algebra, but I think I'm missing some key ah-ha moment in using some trig identity.

So far:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and let $\delta=$ {pending algebra} $>0$. Then for all $x \in I\setminus\{0\}$ where $I$ is some open interval containing $0$, provided $0 < |x| < \delta$,

$$\left|x \cos \left(\frac{x^2+1}{x}\right) - 0\right|=|x| \left|\cos \left(\frac{x^2+1}{x}\right)\right|$$

...at this point I'm not sure. I have a feeling there's a trig identity or something really obvious from calc I I am missing. Any tips appreciated.

Please don't do the whole proof. I'm a student trying to learn. ;)

Comment: You don't need that $g$ has limit, you only need it be bounded, so that $|xg| \le C|x|.$

Comment: So then, I can think of g like a bounded sequence sort-of?

Comment: Can you show that $g$ is bounded (think of $\cos$)

Comment: By boundedness of $\cos$ (which is not a theorem, it is by definition of $\cos$) , we have that $|x||\cos \frac{x^2 + 1}{x}| \leq |x|$. Hence, you can check that taking $\delta = \epsilon$ would do the job.

Comment: Okay, help me understand this though: $\lim_{x\to \infty}$ $cos(\frac1x)$ does not exist. But it is bounded. Is it the existence of the limit of x that makes this different?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг - by **which** definition of $\cos$? There are several equivalent ones, and at least a few do not contain anything about boundedness.

Comment: You might learn some helpful tricks by rereading the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @mathguy The proof of boundedness is by the fact that whatever definition of sine and cosine we use (for the real numbers), then $\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$, hence both must lie between $1$ and $-1$. And the reason why $\cos(\frac 1x)$ does not exist is because a bounded function itself does not imply convergence : for example, take $\cos x$ as $x \to \infty$, which is your example. However, the presence of $x$ in the above example helps bring the fact that we can bound $|x|$ using $\delta$, into play.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг - exactly! That is a *proof*, so it’s not by definition.

Comment: @mathguy Oh, yes, of course, however small it is, it still requires a proof. I apologize.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I'm in the MathJax page. Just have this annoying habit of not simultaneously assimilating all information. The \frac syntax with functions is vexing me just now. Tips?

Comment: @AndyDufresne Read through the coding for the edits I’ve made

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Thank you! Can you tell me offhand, is there a square symbol in lieu of QED? If there is, I cannot locate anything addressing that in the MathJax lit.

Comment: @AndyDufresne For superscript, you’ll want to do something like `a^{bc}` $a^{bc}$, if that’s what your asking.

Comment: @AndyDufresne OH! Now I understand! Haha! `\Box` $\Box$. [This app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/latex-help/id307772257?mt=8) is great as well

Answer (score 1):

We show that $\lim_{x\to 0} x \cos\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x}\right)$ = 0.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and choose $\delta$ = $\varepsilon$. Then for all $x \in I\setminus\{0\}$ where $I$ is some open interval containing $0$, provided $0 < |x| < \delta$,

$$\left| x  \cos\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x}\right) - 0\right|=\left|x\right| \left|\cos\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x}\right)\right|.$$

Now, $\forall x \in$ I, $\left|\cos\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x}\right)\right|\le$ 1, so we have

$$|x| \left|\cos\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x}\right)\right|\le |x| < \delta < \varepsilon$$

as required. QED.

Comment: That's all. I don't see anything to elaborate above.